# New to VBScript and trying to do a nested For Each loop

Tags: foreach, vbscript

I picked up VBScript yesterday, and I am trying to take in a file, copy the file, change some text within the file and output a new file with a new name. The file is copying and saving in the correct location, however I am not sure where my code is wrong. The 'filter' text is changing in all of the files but it is only changing to filter(14).

Any help, guidance or instruction is greatly appreciated. I've placed the code I have so far below:

```
  Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim outputFile(14)
outputFile(0) = "MMCLAgenda_BehavioralHealth.txt"
outputFile(1) ="MMCLAgenda_CaseandCareSupport.txt"
outputFile(2) ="MMCLAgenda_CaseManagement.txt"
outputFile(3) ="MMCLAgenda_ChangeOrder.txt"
outputFile(4) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_BehavioralHealth.txt"
outputFile(5) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_Overarching.txt"
outputFile(6) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_PhysicalHealth.txt"
outputFile(7) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_Supervisors.txt"
outputFile(8) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_SupportStaff.txt"
outputFile(9) ="MMCLAgenda_DM_Workgroups.txt"
outputFile(10) ="MMCLAgenda_InpatientUM.txt"
outputFile(11) ="MMCLAgenda_LeadershipCommittee.txt"
outputFile(12) ="MMCLAgenda_OutpatientUM.txt"
outputFile(13) ="MMCLAgenda_PolicyAndProcedureGroup.txt"
outputFile(14) ="MMCLAgenda_UMCommittee.txt"

Dim filter(14)
filter(0) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Behavior Health' : 'Behavioral Health'</Formula>"
filter(1) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Medical Management Call Center'</Formula>"
filter(2) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Case Management'</Formula>"
filter(3) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Change Orders'</Formula>"
filter(4) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Disease Management/Behavior Health/Anxiety' : 'DM Behavioral Health - Anxiety and Depression'</Formula>"
filter(5) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Disease Management/Overarching'</Formula>"
filter(6) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name =  'Disease Management/Clinical Staff'</Formula>"
filter(7) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31) &amp; COL_Name = 'Disease Management/Supervisors'</Formula>"
filter(8) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31) &amp; COL_Name = 'Disease Management/Support Staff'</Formula>"
filter(9) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)</Formula>"
filter(10) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Transitional Care'</Formula>"
filter(11) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Leadership Committee'</Formula>"
filter(12) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31) &amp; COL_Name = 'Utilization Management'</Formula>"
filter(13) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'Policy &amp; Procedures Workgroup'</Formula>"
filter(14) = "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015;12;31)&amp; COL_Name = 'TEST'</Formula>"

Dim destination(14)
destination(0) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/BH"
destination(1) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/CCS"
destination(2) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/CM"
destination(3) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/CO"
destination(4) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMBH"
destination(5) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMO"
destination(6) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMPH"
destination(7) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMS"
destination(8) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMSS"
destination(9) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/DMW"
destination(10) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/IUM"
destination(11) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/LC"
destination(12) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/OUM"
destination(13) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/PPG"
destination(14) = "https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL/UMC"

fileLocation = "C:\Users\HN142083\Desktop\MigrationJobAutomation\Jobs\"



'**********************************************************************************************************************************
'***for each file in outputFiles -> take FileIn, FileOut = outputFiles(i) -> change strNewText and change destination -> go next***
'**********************************************************************************************************************************

For each x in outputFile

    FileIn = "C:\Users\HN142083\Desktop\MigrationJobAutomation\Jobs\MMCLAgenda_BehavioralHealth.txt"
    FileOut = fileLocation+x

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileIn, ForReading)

    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    strTextDestination = strText
    objFile.Close


        For each item in filter

            strNewText = Replace(strText, "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015; 12; 31)</Formula>", item)
        Next

        For each record in destination
            strTextDestination = Replace(strTextDestination, "<Web>https://testcnet.centene.com/sites/LNTestMigration/Issac/MMCL</Web>", record)
        Next

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileOut, ForWriting)
    objFile.WriteLine strNewText
    objFile.Close


Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this loop

```
For each item in filter
    strNewText = Replace(strText, "<Formula>@Created &gt; @Date(2015; 12; 31)</Formula>", item)
Next
```

is executed for every item against `strText`, which you set to be the content of the file `x`.  On the first iteration of the `filter` loop the `strNewText` variable is set to the replaced version of `strText` using `filter(0)`.  Then it's set to the replaced version of `strText` using `filter(1)` and so on, until `filter(14)` after which the loop is complete and `strNewText` is no longer being set.

`strText` is never being changed, so effectively the loop just gives `strNewText` the equivalent of the replace using only `filter(14)`.

Let me know if that needs further explanation?

Comment: so would I move the strText = objFile.Readall to be within the filter loop?

Comment: No - If you want the text to change including each and every item in the `filter` array, you would need to use `strText = Replace(strText, "...")` so that the `strText` value is updated with each replace statement.

Comment: However, the first time you replace that text with the first `filter` item, it won't be there in `strText` for the next item to find and replace...

Comment: so would you have an idea on how to approach this so that each item is processed correctly? I'm very new and need some strong guidance lol

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do - by default `Replace` will replace all instances of the `find_string` component, but it does have a `count` optional property which you can use to specify that only the first instance of the found string should change.  This link is for `vba` but the majority of the info matches `vbscript`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function

Comment: I appreciate the insight, I will keep working on it to get it working. This has been very helpful in determining where it was broken!